# Load Specific Image for Mobile and Desktop with Facebook's Open Graph

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-opengraph, desktop

Hello I have written a method that generates an image with specific text based on which link the User is sharing to Facebook. This method, when called from a browser/Facebook returns the generated image, but also A different image when called from a mobile browser.

My goal is to be able to display different images based on whether the facebook user is in desktop or mobile app/platform. Does anyone know of any solutions?

Thank You!

Comment: You can specify multiple og:images, and you can specify their dimensions upfront as well. But that will not “guarantee” that Facebook will always pick the image you want for a specific display situation.